# Latex - Changing behavior of encoding in the same document

Tags: input

Currently, I am **trying to achieve a German inputencoding (`inputenc`)** for my thesis. My solution works just fine with a small exception: Whenever my umlauts are correctly input-encoded in the normal text, they are misinterpreted when it comes to my inputs/equation labels and vice versa.

My tex-document-header looks like this:

```
\documentclass[bibtotoc,liststotoc,BCOR0mm,DIV12]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}

%choose font_________________________________________________
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% GERMAN language configs
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ngerman} % deutsche Verzeichnisse

\fontfamily{phv}

%____________________________________________________________
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}

\graphicspath{{./img/}}

\input{hyphenation}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}

\newcommand{\rl}{\raggedleft}
\newcommand{\rr}{\raggedright}
\newcommand{\tn}{\tabularnewline}
```

When I am using `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` the input is correct for the normal text. Exchanging this with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` works for inputs/equations. Here is an example of what would be inserted via `\input{...}`:

```
\begin{equation}
C = \frac{T \cdot W}{L} = \frac{K \cdot A}{L}
\label{eq:Conductance}
\end{equation}
\begin{spacing}{1}\begin{flushleft}
$C$: Leitfähigkeit (hydraulic conductance) [$\frac{m^{2}}{s}$] \\
$T$: Transmissivität [$\frac{m^{2}}{s}$] \\
$W$: durchflossene Breite [$m$] \\
$L$: durchflossene Länge [$m$] \\
$K$: hydraulische Leitfähigkeit [$\frac{m}{s}$] \\
$A$: durchflossene Fläche [$m^{2}$] \\
\end{flushleft}\end{spacing}
```

**I would like to know how I can encode the input, so that both normal text and equation labels are interpreted in the right manner.** If it isn't possible: How about a workaround? I would defenitely prefer a workaround for which I have to change as less as possible.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should configure your editor properly to use the same encoding for all files! BTW, you should really have a look at the package `siunitx` to typeset your units properly. And you shouldn't use square brackets to show the units, that means 'unit of', so that `[W] = m` would be correct. Use round braces or write e.g. `(in \si{\m})`.

Comment: @Christoph, putting the units in quare brackets is a common geophysical standard. There might be more readable implementations of typing units in general. I will have a look in the editor configurations, though. A lot of my equations are from a previous work. There is the possibility that the copied latex-code simply has a different encoding.

Comment: Concerning typing units, see http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/checklist.html. Besides the aesthetical and typographic aspect it is very important in order to distinguish e.g. between *m* as variable for the mass and unit for *metre*. Using packages like `siunitx` relieves you from thinking too much about it and beeing consistent.

Comment: I will add the comprehensive final solution as soon as tex.stackexchange let me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is much better to ensure that all files have the same encoding, but in principle you can switch encoding mid document.

To input a utf-8 encoded file into an ISO-8859-1 encoded document:

```
\inputencoding{utf8}
\input{..}
\inputencoding{latin1}
```

Comment: Principally, the `\inputencoding{...}`-solution should have worked. The reason why id didn't is not quite clear. My best guess: The way how equations and their labels are organized is defined in the header. If I enforce a default `inputenc` of `latin1`, I cannot fully change the encoding for the code constructs (which are defined in the header) completely.

Answer (score 0):

It was the different file encoding which caused problems in the `inputenc`-configuration. I've had to manually reset the file encoding by saving them again with the appropiate options. The reason for the differnt ecoding was Notepad++. On my system it uses a different standard encoding for textfiles and I used the editor to quickly create the tex-scripts.

The answer of @DavidCarlisle provides a workaround if somebody does not want to change the originally encoding of inputted/included files:

```
\inputencoding{utf8}    % temporary file encoding
\input{..}
\inputencoding{latin1}  % orignal file encoding
```